# Angular Material Buttons not matching theme

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I just have installed Angular 10 with Angular Materials `ng add @angular/material`

There I choose the custom theme: **Purple/Green**

Next step was to simply add a Toolbar, basically copy paste from googles site. But I cannot arrange the buttons matching the theme. I have no idea why it looks like this.

[image]

**how it should look**

[image]

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>My App</span>
  <span class="nav-spacer"></span>
  <button mat-icon-button class="material-icons-outlined" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
    <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

my stlye.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and these imports

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
```

What do I miss here please?

Comment: You have to import the theme css file into your css file. **@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; **

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add MatButtonModule in your imports.